# Is it possible to combine the following pattern?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching

I want to simplify the following pattern

```
Cases[Permutations[Range@3], {___, 2, 3, ___} | {___, 3, 2, ___}]
```

into something like (but it does not compile).

```
Cases[Permutations[Range@3], {___, (2, 3) | (3, 2), ___}]
```

Please let me know if it can be simplified.

Comment: `Cases[Permutations[Range@3], {___, 2 | 3, 3 | 2, ___}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This updated example has an easy fix with [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html).

```
Permutations[Range@3]
Cases[%, {___, OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 3], ___}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}

**Side note:** That being said.  I was working on this before the edit and I noticed interesting, seemingly wrong, behavior.

Basically, naming a pattern effects matching.  For example

```
MatchQ[{1, 4, 3, 2}, {l___, seq : OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 3], r___}]
```

returns `False` where as

```
MatchQ[{1, 4, 3, 2}, {l___, OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 3], r___}]
```

returns `True`.  It's also interesting and should be noted that

```
MatchQ[{1, 4, 2, 3}, seq : {l___, OrderlessPatternSequence[3, 2], r___}];
MatchQ[{1, 4, 2, 3}, {l___, OrderlessPatternSequence[3, 2], r___}];
%% === % === True
```

> True

There's also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118157/46490) confirmed bug to a similar situation.
This might be better actually asked a separate question, but I just wanted to see if there was something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: You should report this misbehavior to "OrderlessPatternSequence" to Wolfram

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, will do.