# Assign a name for OrderlessPatternSequence

Tags: pattern-matching

```
MatchQ[f[x, y, z], f[OrderlessPatternSequence[z, a_, y]]]
MatchQ[f[x, cqq, cq], f[OrderlessPatternSequence[cq, a_, cqq]]]

MatchQ[f[x, y, z], f[h : OrderlessPatternSequence[z, a_, y]]]
MatchQ[f[x, cqq, cq], f[h : OrderlessPatternSequence[cq, a_, cqq]]]
```

The first two lines of course return True, but the last two lines return True and False respectively.
Similarly example like

```
MatchQ[f[z, y, x], f[h : OrderlessPatternSequence[z, y , x]]]
```

returns False.

To makes sure whether it is allowed to assign a name for `OrderlessPatternSequence`, I find this in offical document

```
Replace[{1, "a", 2, "b"}, {a : OrderlessPatternSequence[__Integer, __String]} :> a]
```

So I'm quite confused. Hope somebody can point out my mistake or give a possible explaination。

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. I think this might be a bug, see for example [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239653/75628).

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful

Comment: I think this is a bug, because the full form: `MatchQ[f[x, cqq, cq], 
 Pattern[h, f[OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, cqq, cq]]]] `returns True. Please report it to support@wolfrasm.com